# How to use vert.x shell to monitor message traffic

Tags: vert.x

I have a simple verticle, which receives a string as input and replies with another string. I was planning to use vert.x shell (telnet) to send and publish messages using `bus-send` and `bus-publish`. However these methods does not seem to interact with the local bus. Any ideas what might go wrong?

I want to have a behavior similar to `dbus-send`and `dbus-monitor`utilities in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shell is started as it is [stated](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-shell/java/#_using_vert_x_shell) in the docs:

```
vertx run -conf '{"telnetOptions":{"port":5000}}' maven:io.vertx:vertx-shell:3.2.1
```

it wont be able to commuicate with other verticles, as it is not in any cluster. The solution is to add `--cluster` and `--cluster-host` flags:

```
vertx run -conf '{"telnetOptions":{"port":5000}}' maven:io.vertx:vertx-shell:3.2.1 --cluster --cluster-host localhost
```